# arma::SpMat<short> input in RcppArmadillo function

Tags: c++, r, sparse-matrix, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I wrote a C++ function via `Rcpp`, `RcppArmadillo` etc. that returns an `arma::SpMat<short>`, i.e. a sparse matrix. It shows up as a `dgCMatrix` in the R environment.

At a later stage, I want to insert the returned object into another C++ function. However, when trying to compile that function, the compiler throws more than 1000 lines of error messages. You can replicate them using the following minimal working example:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
#include <iostream>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat some_function(arma::SpMat<short> x, arma::mat y) {
  return y;
}')
```

The issue appears to be the data type of the matrix. The compiler does not throw the respective errors when using a sparse matrix of type `double` rather than one of type `short`:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
#include <iostream>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat some_function(arma::sp_mat x, arma::mat y) {
  return y;
}')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: R only has support for `int` and `double`.  So _automatically generated_ interfaces are limited to those types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks. Based on your comment I tried compiling the function with `arma::SpMat<int>`. Unfortunately, that does not work either.

Comment: Check the RcppArmadillo header files -- maybe we only wrap the (default) `spmat` defaulting to a double though that would surprise me...

Comment: Note that you _cannot_ have a signature like `arma::mat some_function(arma::SpMat<short> x, arma::mat y) ` in function you want to export to R as that uses a _C foreign function interface_ so no templates here.

Comment: Thanks. I am not deep enough into this to follow your point. The issue is that the mentioned signature uses a C foreign function interface rather than a Rcpp/ RcppArmadillo template, right? Why is that the case? Which part of the signature forces the code to use a C foreign function interface? Sorry to bother you with probably trivial questions. I am still rather new to Rcpp.

Comment: It's exactly as I said: an _interface_ function accessed by _both_ laguages has to satisfy both language constraints. C has no templates.